# Threshold for non-zero quantum capacity of depolarizing channels

Tags: it.information-theory, quantum-information

In ["Quantum-channel capacity of very noisy channels"](http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v57/i2/p830_1), DiVincenzo, Shor and Smolin showed that it is possible to perform quantum communication over depolarizing channels provided that the fidelity was greater than 0.80944. What I want to know is the lowest value known for the fidelity such that quantum communication is still possible. Does anyone know the current state of the art with respect to this problem?